# Override DVD system in c#

Tags: c#, dvd, windows-media-center

I've been wanting to write my own version of DVD override software for some time now.  I really want it to behave like AnyDVD, except much less overhead and not near as many options.

Basically I want to be able to insert a DVD on my Media Center and have the option of "Start Main Movie" or "Go to Main Menu".

I don't need to decrypt CSS (at least I don't think I have to). I just want to override the PUOPS (prohibited user operations) so that I can navigate anywhere on the disc.

I'm decent with c#, but I've never worked with a DVD drive or playback before.  I've scoured the web but found nothing.

Has anyone out there done this before?  What resources can I look to for this task?

Thanks for a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Something tells me you're not the first person who wants to disable the PUOPS...

Comment: Basically you need to implement an entire DVD player, in which case I suggest looking at some open source players like VLC. (and yeah I know this is an old question, but I'm leaving this here for anyone else ending here via google)